# How to configure fcgid.conf for Wt (Witty) C++ Web Application?

Tags: linux, configuration, web-applications, mod-fcgid

I am trying to configure fcgid.conf file for Wt (witty-web toolkit) for apache2 2.4 on Ubuntu 23. I found a config file for FastCGI (not fcgid) and convert commands to fcgid ones using apache2 web page. But one is left FastCgiServer /var/www/html/hello.wt

Here is my full code:

```
  AddHandler fcgid-script .wt
  FcgidIPCDir /var/lib/apache2/fcgid
  FcgidIdleTimeout 100
  FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 1
  FcgidInitialEnv WT_APP_ROOT=/tmp
#  FastCgiServer /var/www/html/hello.wt (I want to find the equivalence for fcgid) 
  <IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

How can I configure for witty? There is not enough documentation for this.

EDIT:

I changed fcgid.conf to:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.0c>
  AddHandler fcgid-script .wt
  FcgidIPCDir /var/lib/apache2/fcgid
  FcgidIdleTimeout 100
  FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 1
  FcgidInitialEnv WT_APP_ROOT=/tmp

   <Directory /var/www/html>
       Options +ExecCGI
       FcgidWrapper /var/www/html .wt
       Order deny,allow
   </Directory>

  <IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

and hello.conf file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName hello
    ServerAlias www.hello
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
   <Directory "/var/www/html">
      Options +ExecCGI +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      AllowOverride None
       Order deny,allow
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

No error but the the results is:

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B8Ep.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `fcgid.conf` file There is no direct equivalent of `FastCgiServer` in `FCGI`, `FcgidWrapper` directive is commonly used for that.

For your configuration you could use the example below, dont forget to replace `/path/to/your/wt/application`.

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    AddHandler fcgid-script .wt
    FcgidIPCDir /var/lib/apache2/fcgid
    FcgidIdleTimeout 100
    FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 1
    FcgidInitialEnv WT_APP_ROOT=/tmp

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options +ExecCGI
        FcgidWrapper /path/to/your/wt/application .wt
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No error but the web page loads hello.wt in an index. If I click, it just downloads it. May there be a problem with WT compilation? It takes too much to compile and I am not sure If I did it correct.

Comment: By the way, I haven't mention hello.wt in anywhere. How will apache know it would run hello.wt?

Comment: it means that the server isn't recognizing hello.wt as a script it needs to execute. And for your second question Apache will attempt to run any *.wt file it encounters using the application specified in the FcgidWrapper directive

Comment: "using the application specified in the FcgidWrapper directive". Should the path of FcgidWrapper direct to an app? Currently, it is directing to hello.wt.

Comment: FcgidWrapper directive should point to the compiled FastCGI application (typically a binary file), not the .wt source file, you gonna need to compile your hello.wt source file into a binary executable using a compiler

Comment: I had started to think what a magic way those servers were working. Now make sense. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You welcome :))